# Using MS Access to add comments to a MS Excel range object

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, late-binding

I am attempting to write a subroutine within a MS Access module that accesses a MS Excel worksheet and adds a comment to a specified range. I am using late binding so that my low-confidence users don't need to fiddle around adding references. When attempting to add comments to a range object, the following error is thrown:

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

With the following example code, assume that the worksheet opened has a Cell A1 with the comment "Hello", Cell A2 with the comment "World", and Cell A3 does not have a comment.

```
Sub export(strFilePath As String)
 Dim XL As Object
 Dim WB as Object
 Dim WS as Object
 Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 XL.Workbooks.Open strFilePath
 Set WB = XL.Workbooks(1)
 Set WS = WB.Sheets("ExportSheet")

 Debug.Print WS.Comments.Count 'returns accurate number of comments on sheet (2)
 Debug.Print WS.Range("a1").Comment.Text 'returns comment of cell A1 (Hello)
 WS.Range("a1").Comment.Delete 'removes comment of cell A1
 Debug.Print WS.Comments.Count 'returns accurate number of comments on sheet (1)
 Debug.Print WS.Range("a2").Comment.Text 'returns comment of cell A2 (World)
 WS.Range("a2").ClearComments 'removes comment of cell A2
 Debug.Print WS.Comments.Count 'returns accurate number of comments on sheet (0)

 WS.Range("a3").AddComment("HelloAgain") 'causes 1004 error
 WS.Range("a3").AddComment "HelloAgain" 'also causes 1004 error, if the above line is commented out

End Sub
```

I am able to access the methods pertaining to comments except for the `range.AddComment` method. **How do I go about adding a comment?**

Comment: Try removing the Parenthesis around "HelloAgain" -->  WS.Range("A3").AddComment "HelloAgain"

Comment: Unfortunately, the same error occurs if the comment is inside of parenthesis or not. I've updated my original post to reflect this.

Comment: Hmm...Does an existing comment exist in A3? I see your clearing comments in A1 & A2, but not A3.  That will throw error 1004 if a comment exists already in that range.

Comment: Fink, the cell A3 does not contain a comment. A few of the answers below suggest clearing the comment from the cell to ensure that a new one can be added. I was able to clear the cell's comment (which didn't exist) with `.ClearComments`, but the `.AddComment` method still throws the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when cell A3 already contains a comment. I was able to reproduce it.

***>>>EDIT - problem occurs when trying to add a comment to any cell***

The problem also occurs if the worksheet is grouped with another worksheet. See http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/did-lose-ability-add-edit-comments-excel-t3837597.html

To reproduce:

1. Open the workbook in Excel, and click on the Sheet1 tab.
2. Holding down the Shift key, click on Sheet2. This causes sheets 1 and 2 to be grouped.
3. Right-click any cell. The "Insert Comment" option is gone!
4. Under Review/Comments, the "New Comment" option is grayed!

To fix:

If this is indeed your problem, then try adding a line of code to ungroup the worksheets.

```
 Set WS = WB.Sheets("ExportSheet")
 WS.Select      ' ungroup worksheets  <-- ADD THIS CODE
```

I discovered how to ungroup the sheets using VBA by recording a macro. I right-clicked on the Sheet tab and chose "Ungroup Sheets", then looked at the generated code.

Comment: Thanks, Tom, but in my explanation I stipulated that cell A3 doesn't have a comment. As in mwolfe02's answer, I tried clearing the comment from the cell to no avail, and the 1004 error still occurs. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you add a comment to A3 from within Excel? After exiting from all MS Office apps, does Task Manager/Processes show any copies of excel.exe still running? Are you doing WB.Close and XL.Quit before your End Sub?

Comment: The spreadsheets had gotten grouped- selecting the single sheet solved the problem. Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because there is already an existing comment.  If you want to overwrite any existing comment, but are not sure whether the cell may already have a comment, you can call the `.ClearComments` method of the Range object.  This will clear any existing comments from the cell but will not raise an error if no comment currently exists.

```
WS.Range("a3").ClearComments
WS.Range("a3").AddComment "HelloAgain"
```

Comment: Thanks, mwolfe02, but in my explanation I stipulated that cell A3 does not have a comment attached to it. Regardless, if I `.ClearComments` the range, I am still unable to run the `.AddComment` method. The same error occurs. Is it possible that the `.AddComment` method may be the problem, and its inaccessible from Access?

Comment: Can you use `.AddComment` on cell A2 after you ClearComments from cell A2?

Comment: No, that does not work either. Each time I call the `.AddComment` method on a range (regardless of if it has a comment or not) it throws the 1004 error.

Comment: If more than one worksheet is selected, ClearComments will work but AddComment will fail. See my edited answer below. (Excel is _sooo_ intuitive!)